$\zeta(2n+1)$ - Is this formulation helpful?
Cross-posting alert: I posted This on MSE. I read through the guidelines for cross-posting on both the sites and my conclusion is that I am not violating any guidelines.
Briefly, I derived some expressions for $\zeta(2\text{n}+1)$ that have the general format as shown below:
For $\text{n} \ge 1$
$$\zeta(2\text{n}+1) = \frac{2(-1)^{\text{n+1}} (2\pi)^{2\text{n}}}{2\text{n}!} \lim\limits_{\text{N} \to \infty} \left[ \left\{ \sum\limits_{\text{k}=1}^{\text{N}} \text{k}^{2\text{n}} \text{log}(\text{k})\right\} - \left\{ \text{log}(\text{N})\sum\limits_{\text{k}=1}^{\text{N}}\text{k}^{2\text{n}}\right\} + \text{P}_{2\text{n}+1}(\text{N})\right]
$$
where $\text{P}_{2\text{n}+1}(\text{N})$ is a polynomial of degree $2\text{n}+1$ of the variable $\text{N}$ involving only odd powers of $\text{N}$.
For example,
$$\zeta(3) = 4\pi^2 \lim\limits_{\text{N} \to \infty} \left[ \left\{ \sum\limits_{\text{k}=1}^{\text{N}} \text{k}^{2} \text{log}(\text{k})\right\} - \left\{ \text{log}(\text{N})\sum\limits_{\text{k}=1}^{\text{N}}\text{k}^{2}\right\} + \frac{\text{N}^3}{9}-\frac{\text{N}}{12}\right]
$$
$$\zeta(5) = \frac{-4}{3}\pi^4 \lim\limits_{\text{N} \to \infty} \left[ \left\{ \sum\limits_{\text{k}=1}^{\text{N}} \text{k}^{4} \text{log}(\text{k})\right\} - \left\{ \text{log}(\text{N})\sum\limits_{\text{k}=1}^{\text{N}}\text{k}^{4}\right\} + \frac{\text{N}^5}{25} -\frac{\text{N}^3}{12}+\frac{\text{13N}}{360}\right]
$$
$$\zeta(7) = \frac{16}{90}\pi^6 \lim\limits_{\text{N} \to \infty} \left[ \left\{ \sum\limits_{\text{k}=1}^{\text{N}} \text{k}^{6} \text{log}(\text{k})\right\} - \left\{ \text{log}(\text{N})\sum\limits_{\text{k}=1}^{\text{N}}\text{k}^{6}\right\} + \frac{\text{N}^7}{49}-\frac{\text{N}^5}{12} +\frac{37\text{N}^3}{360}-\frac{\text{29N}}{840}\right]
$$
Questions

Though this formulation bears similarity to genralized Zeta function or Hurwitz Zeta formulation involving logarithms, I have not seen these expressions precisely in literature upon a general search. Is my assumption correct that these are new formulations?
Are these formulations helpful in proving any other properties like irrationality? I am talking about irrationality of $\frac{\zeta(3)}{\pi^2}$ , $\frac{\zeta(5)}{\pi^4}$, etc... Intuitively, I see the $\text{P}_{2\text{n}+1}(\text{N})$ to be rational no matter how large $\text{N}$ becomes. I was hoping this community might see some rigorous way to prove that the difference between the 2 infinite sums involving logarithms to be irrational, which when added to the rational number from the polynomial will result in $\frac{\zeta(2\text{n}+1)}{(2\pi)^{2\text{n}}}$ to become irrational.

Edit: Removed the note talking about my work in progress. The formula for P(N) from Henri (in the answer I accepted) is elegant and there is no need for mine (which was turning out to be long anyway).

I think questions like "can we prove statement X this way" are not appropriate here. In addition, please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075/

Why use, for example, \lim\limits_{\text{N}->\infty} instead of \lim\limits_{N \to \infty} (or you can drop \limits, since it's in display mode)?  I'd normally edit to fix this, but, since you're consistently using \text for math-mode variables, it must be intentional. \ @GHfromMO, re, I'd agree that this post probably doesn't belong here, but with different emphasis. A question of the form "can X be proven using Y?", if well asked, can be well received, but I think "here's Y, what can it prove?" usually isn't.

@LSpice. Thanks for your suggestions. I replaced "->" with $\to$. I used \text so that the variables are not italicized. Sorry I am new to MathJax and still learning. I see your point about my open ended question. On MSE, I ask very directed questions. I am aware that these sites are not for general philosophical musings. This being my first post here, I hope you will forgive this instance and be kind enough not to close the thread.

Also, it seems a bit silly now that I have highlighted in red that I making progress with the formula for P(N), whereas Henri Cohen has indicated that it is already in his book as a mere exercise problem. I am very curious to see his final answer posting the formula. At that point, I will accept his answer and hopefully this thread will end naturally. Thanks to all for patience until then. From what I have already worked out my formula for P(N) is nowhere elegant or succint.

I recommend looking through the literature here and here. There does exist quite a bit of known theory about Glaisher-Kinkelin-like constants.

This follows directly from the Euler-MacLaurin formula applied
to $\sum_{1\le m<N}m^{2k}\log(m)$: the constant term is essentially
$\zeta'(-2k)$, itself directly related via the functional equation to
$\zeta(2k+1)/\pi^{2k}$. You can find the precise formula as Exercise 44 (b)
of Chapter 9 (page 129) of my Springer GTM 240, and in particular the
exact formula for your polynomial $P_{2k+1}(N)$.
Added: at the request of the OP, the formula is
$$P_{2k+1}(N)=\dfrac{1}{2k+1}\sum_{j=0}^{2k}\binom{2k+1}{j}H_{2k+1-j}B_jN^{2k+1-j}-\dfrac{B_{2k+1}(N)}{2k+1}H_{2k}$$
where $B_j$ and $B_j(N)$ are the Bernoulli numbers and polynomials,
and $H_m=\sum_{1\le j\le m}1/j$ is the $m$th harmonic sum.
You can slightly simplify this by replacing the Bernoulli polynomial by its explicit expression.

Thanks @HenriCohen. Do you mind posting the exact formula for P(N) from your book?

I welcome anyone (especially the currently 9 upvoters who found this answer useful) to post the explicit formula for P(N) either as a comment or as a separate answer.

@Srini https://www.libgen.is/ . Some might tell you it is illegal to get books for free, but I don't see how it is illegal when it is helping to spread the democracy.

Thanks Henri for posting the formula. What is the variable x in your formula? Typo?

Yes, typo. Removed.

Thanks. Your formula is elegant.
